# NumericUpDown base location moves if visibility is toggled during a scroll

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, numericupdown

I'm working on a school project for a restaurant menu. I have my menu items in a TabControl based on type (main course, salads, deserts, and beverages). The main course menu has lots of items and it required me to set the AutoScroll of that TabsPage to `true`.

The menu works by clicking the picture of the item, which makes the quantity Label visible along with a NumericUpDown control used to keep track of the quantity. Each click of the image increments the quantity by 1. If you manually go to `0`, it will make the quantity Label and NumericUpDown control not visible again.

The issue I'm having is that if I happen to scroll down before I click a main menu item, the NumericUpDown control moves along with the scroll and gets out of its predefined position.
This does not happen with quantity image however. I tried to lock it in the properties but it doesn't make a difference. Also, this does not happen to the other tabs menu items and doesn't happen in the main menu tab page if I did not use the scroll.

```
private void picPesto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        nudPesto.Value++;
        nudPesto.Visible = true;
        lblPestoQuantity.Visible = true;
    }

    private void nudPesto_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (nudPesto.Value == 0)
        {
            lblPestoQuantity.Visible = false;
            nudPesto.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

[Base program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDSUv.jpg)

[How it should display quantity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIyMr.jpg)

[image: numericUpDown made visible after moving scroll down]

Comment: What is the `Anchor` property of the NumericUpDowns set to?

Comment: top left for all of them

Comment: If that Control is not visible when its TagPage is selected, its handle is not created, thus the Layout is not performed. The Layout is only applied when you make it visible, so the Layout will apply the TabPage's DisplayRectangle offset (since the DisplayRectangle will have a negative `Y` value, the `0` is `0 + ABS(Offset)`), moving the Control downwards. You can force the handle creation of all invisible Control beforehand, so the LayoutEngine can work on it.

Comment: Note that the handles of visible Controls that belong to TabPages that are not visible when the parent Form is shown are not created until you select their TabPage container.  The handles of invisible Controls are only created when you set their `Visible` property to `true` (which,a s described, can cause - among the others - the issue you mentioned). -- The Lock Property has nothing to do with this, it's used to fix a Control's position at Design-Time only.

Comment: BTW, you should not use a PictureBox AND a NumericUpDown AND a Label. You should build a UserControl that contains these child Controls, so you add just ONE object to a TabPage and (if required) create the handles of the UC child Controls when the UC itself is created (its `OnHandleCreated` method is called).